# How do I get statistics of column "RetailSales2014"?

Tags: r

So "RetailSales2014" contains money values. I know I need to remove the commas to perform statistical analysis, but do I also need to remove the leading '$' symbols too? If I do, how would I remove them?

```
# Load packages
```

library("XML")
library("RCurl")

## Specify URL

url <- "https://nrf.com/2015/top100-table"

## Download the content of the URL

url_content <- getURL(url)

## Parse the HTML/XML content to generate an R structure representing the HTML/XML tree

doc <- htmlParse(url_content)

tables <- readHTMLTable(doc)

## Convert the 3rd element of the list to data frame

retailer_df <- data.frame(tables)

attributes(retailer_df)

## Rename retailer_df columns

colnames(retailer_df) <- c("Rank","Company","Headquarter","RetailSales2014","USASalesGrowth","WorldwideRetailSales","USAPercentageOfWorldwideSales","Stores2014","Growth")

summary(retailer_df)

## Write the retailer data into csv file under the working directory

write.csv(retailer_df, file = "top100retailers2015.csv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
retailer_df$RetailSales2014 <- 
    as.numeric(gsub("(\\D)", "", retailer_df$RetailSales2014))
```

Comment: That worked! Our professor is going to teach us how to do this later this week, but I wanted to get a head-start on understanding numeric conversion.

Comment: No. The assignment was already finished with the code I provided. One of the questions was "Show summary statistics of the dataset. Do you get min, median, mean, and max values of the RetailSales2014 variable? Why? Put your answers in the following box." That is the exact wording. I am not cheating and to be frank, I think this community isn't very welcoming to students trying to learn R....